# What is the logic behind desktops location on macos?

Tags: macos

I'm talking about virtual desktops, you can see them when you swipe up 3 fingers. When I create multiple desktops after sometime their location change. and lets say I have two desktops and I have Chrome on the left one, full screen and firefox in right desktop fullscreen, the desktop for firefox will go to the right side after some time.. Why its location change after sometime, I'm sure there is a logic here I just can't figure it out.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want them to rearrange, then turn off **Automatically rearrange Spaces**.

[image]